# How to implement this kind of loader when changing routes on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nen8E.png)

Good day people, please am trying to implement this kind of loading and spinner when am changing routes in react, can anyone here help me out with the code. I use `react-router-dom`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/implementing-a-react-progress-bar-with-redux-4bc2a35c99ce) tutorial by medium, it shows an useful example.

Answer (score 0):

add this to Header or index.html or index.js(parent component)

```
<progress value="20" max='100'></progress>
```

add jquery to that html page by

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

then below this script tag add this

```
    <script>
      $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('progress').val(($(window)[0].scrollY+$(window)[0].innerHeight)*100/$(document).height())
        })
    </script>
```

**Note** you can style that progress bar by css

```
progress{
 ...//css
}
```